# Why is Krishna called Chola Putri Priya

Tags: krishna, name

Why is Krishna called as Chola Putri Priya, is there a specific reason?

Comment: Where did you hear that Krishna is called Chola Putri Priya?  I'm not familiar with that name.

Comment: @Keshav Maybe like Kulasekhara Perumal's daughter even a Chozha Princess married Ranganatha.

Comment: @Keshav Ah it is Uraiyur Nachiyar [see here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azhagiya_Manavala_Perumal_Temple)

Comment: @Surya Kulasekhara Alwar was a Chera king, which is why his daughter was known as Cherakulavalli.  But yeah, Kamalavali Nachiyar was a Chola princess.

Comment: @Keshav Yeah so Kamalavalli Nachiyar is the Chozha Putri who is priya to Ranganatha.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason he is called because he married Chola king's daughter. This story is associated with [Azhagiya Manavala Perumal Temple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azhagiya_Manavala_Perumal_Temple), A divyadesham glorified by Kulasekhara Alwar and Tirumangai Alwar in Nalayira Divya Prabandham. Lord's consort Lakshmi is worshipped as Kamalavalli Nachiyar here.

**[Here](http://www.divyadesam.com/hindu/temples/trichy/tirukozhi-temple.shtml)'s the legend:**

> A king by named Dharma Varman lived in Kumbakonam, Chozha Naadu. Once he went out for hunting and found the rishis were being distressed by some demons and sought the help from the king. Dharma Varman said that he will help them from the demons by killing them and he stayed in the forest for sometime. The King was happy for all the reason but only one thing made him worry and disappoint and that is he had no children. He sought the help of the rishis to help him out and to get children. So, to help the king, all the rishis did a Yagam to get a child for the king. At that time, an Asareeri stated that if he want to get a child he should pray towards Sri Lakshmi and as a result, **Sri Lakshmi itself will born as a child to him. Hearing this, he started to pray towards Sri Lakshmi and finally, The king found a girl child in a lotus tank while hunting in a forest**. Since the child was born out of lotus, she was named Kamalavalli by the king. Time came when Kamalavalli fell in love with Vishnu in the form of Ranganathar, the presiding deity of Srirangam Ranganathaswamy temple. **The Chola king readily got her married to Ranganathar**. He built a temple to commemorate the occasion. The event is celebrated as Serthi Sevai festival every year. Since Vishnu appeared as Azhagiya Manavalan, meaning a beautiful groom, the temple is called Azhagiya Manavalan Temple.

Due to this reason, Krishna(Ranganatha) is called as Chola Putri priya(The one who loved the daughter of Chola King).